Django Test Environment Runs Twice and Fails When Using if not IS_PRODUCTION and INJECT_FAKE_DATA
Description:
I'm encountering a strange issue in my Django test environment. When running my test suite, the environment appears to initialize twice, causing a specific test to pass the first time and fail on the second run. The problem seems to be related to the following conditional statement in my settings.py file:
if not IS_PRODUCTION and INJECT_FAKE_DATA:
    # Code for injecting fake data

Environment Details:

Django version: 5.1.1
Python version: 3.12.1
Test Framework: pytest with pytest-django
Database: MongoDB for test

What Happens:

When I run my tests, the environment is reloaded twice (as evidenced by logs).
On the first initialization, everything works as expected, and the test passes.
On the second run, the same test fails due to the environment not behaving as intended.

INFO:C:\path\to\settings.py changed, reloading.
INFO:INJECT_FAKE_DATA is True.
INFO:Fake data mode activated.
INFO:Watching for file changes with StatReloader
...
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
...
First run: test passes.
Second run: test fails with inconsistent state.

and
PS C:\Users\Chevr\OneDrive\Bureau\eOnsight\eOnsightApi\eonsight-api> pytest app_auth
============================================================= test session starts ==============================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.12.1, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
django: version: 5.1.1, settings: eOnsight_api.settings (from ini)
rootdir: C:\Users\Chevr\OneDrive\Bureau\eOnsight\eOnsightApi\eonsight-api
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: Faker-30.0.0, django-4.9.0, factoryboy-2.7.0, mongo-3.1.0
collected 2 items

app_auth/tests/test_auth_viewset.py::test_login PASSED                                                                                    [ 50%]
app_auth/tests/test_auth_viewset.py::test_login ERROR                                                                                     [ 50%]
app_auth/tests/test_auth_viewset.py::test_logout PASSED                                                                                   [100%]
app_auth/tests/test_auth_viewset.py::test_logout ERROR                                                                                    [100%] 

==================================================================== ERRORS ==================================================================== 
_______________________________________________________ ERROR at teardown of test_login ________________________________________________________ 

code in setting.py:
# eOnsight_api/settings.py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
from decouple import config
from mongoengine import connect
import mimetypes
from .config.os_specific_paths import OSPaths

from dotenv import load_dotenv 
load_dotenv()

# Get the paths to the GDAL and GEOS libraries based on the current OS
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH, GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = OSPaths.get_gdal_geos_paths()


# Logging configuration
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s:%(message)s',
        },
    },
    'root': { 
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', 'False').lower() == 'true'
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'Default_Key')

# Allowed hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS', '127.0.0.1').split(',')

# Production
IS_PRODUCTION = os.environ.get('IS_PRODUCTION', 'True').lower() == 'true'

# Fake data injection
INJECT_FAKE_DATA = os.getenv('INJECT_FAKE_DATA', 'False').lower() == 'true'

# Base INSTALLED_APPS
INSTALLED_APPS_BASE = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'eOnsight_api.apps.EonsightApiConfig',
    'corsheaders',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'rest_framework',  
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'app_infrastructures',
    'app_users',
    'app_auth'    
]

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['eOnsight_api.config.routers.AuthRouter']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_extensions',

]

# Database-dependent apps
DATABASE_DEPENDENT_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.gis',
]



# Middleware base
MIDDLEWARE_BASE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

# Configuration DRF Spectacular pour le schéma OpenAPI
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'app_users.authentication.MongoJWTAuthentication',
    ),
}


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',  
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id', 
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True, 
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60 * 2),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60 * 4),
}

if 'pytest' in sys.argv:
    MONGODB_URI = config('MONGO_TEST_DB_URI')
    MONGODB_NAME = config('MONGO_TEST_DB_NAME')
else:
    MONGODB_URI = config('MONGO_DB_URI') 
    MONGODB_NAME = config('MONGO_DB_NAME')

# Connect to MongoDB
try:
    connect(
        db=MONGODB_NAME,
        host=MONGODB_URI,
        uuidRepresentation='standard'
    )
    print("Connected to MongoDB")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MongoDB: {e}")

if not IS_PRODUCTION and INJECT_FAKE_DATA:  # Fake data mode
        # Use dummy database backend
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
            }
        }
        INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS_BASE

        # Disable migrations
        class DisableMigrations:
            def __contains__(self, item):
                return True

            def __getitem__(self, item):
                return None

        MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()

        # Adjust middleware
        MIDDLEWARE = MIDDLEWARE_BASE
        
        # Configurer le backend de sessions basé sur les fichiers
        SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
        SESSION_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sessions_fakedata')
        os.makedirs(SESSION_FILE_PATH, exist_ok=True)

else:   # Production mode
        # Database configuration
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
                'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'db_clear'),
                'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER', 'user_clear'),
                'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_clear'),
                'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT', '5432'),
                'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
            }
        }
        INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS_BASE + DATABASE_DEPENDENT_APPS

        # Middleware including database-dependent middleware
        MIDDLEWARE = MIDDLEWARE_BASE + [
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        ]

# URL configuration
ROOT_URLCONF = 'eOnsight_api.urls'

# Templates configuration
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# WSGI application
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eOnsight_api.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Static files
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)

# Default primary key field type
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# REST Framework configuration
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}

# drf_spectacular settings
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'eOnsight API',
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Documentation de l\'API pour eOnsight',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
    'SECURITY': [{
        'apiKeyAuth': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'in': 'header',
            'name': 'Authorization'
        }
    }],
}

# CORS configuration
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:4200",  
]


one off my test app_auth:
import pytest
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework import status
from app_users.models import User
from app_users.service import UserService

@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    return APIClient()

@pytest.fixture
def create_user(mongo_db):
    """
    Fixture pour créer des utilisateurs dans la base MongoDB.
    """
    def _create_user(email=None, password="password123", role="user"):
        if not email:
            email = f"user{User.objects.count()}@example.com" 
        return UserService.create_user(email=email, password=password, role=role)
    return _create_user

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_login(api_client, create_user):
    """
    Test for user login and JWT token retrieval.
    """
    user = create_user(email='testuser@example.com', password='password123')
    payload = {
        'email': user.email,
        'password': 'password123'
    }
    response = api_client.post(reverse('token_obtain_pair'), payload, format='json')
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert 'access' in response.data
    assert 'refresh' in response.data

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_logout(api_client, create_user):
    """
    Test for user logout using both access and refresh tokens.
    """
    user = create_user(email='testuser@example.com', password='password123')
    
    login_payload = {
        'email': user.email,
        'password': 'password123'
    }

    login_response = api_client.post(reverse('token_obtain_pair'), login_payload, format='json')

    assert login_response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK

    access_token = login_response.data['access']
    refresh_token = login_response.data['refresh']

    api_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {access_token}')
    
    print(f'user access token: {access_token}')
    print(f'user refresh token: {refresh_token}')

    logout_payload = {
        'refresh_token': refresh_token
    }

    logout_response = api_client.post(reverse('logout'), logout_payload, format='json')

    assert logout_response.status_code == status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT
    assert logout_response.data['success'] == 'Tokens have been invalidated successfully'


Steps to Reproduce:

Set the environment variables IS_PRODUCTION=False and INJECT_FAKE_DATA=True.
Run the test suite using pytest with pytest-django.
Observe that the test passes on the first run and fails on the second due to inconsistent state.

What I've Tried:

Using @override_settings in tests to ensure IS_PRODUCTION and INJECT_FAKE_DATA are correctly set.
Forcing IS_PRODUCTION and INJECT_FAKE_DATA to be explicit booleans in settings.py.
Disabling the file watcher (--noreload) during test execution.
Logging the values of IS_PRODUCTION and INJECT_FAKE_DATA to ensure they are correctly set.
The bug disappears when comparing IS_PRODUCTION and INJECT_FAKE_DATA as strings, like this but this os not a consistent solution:

if IS_PRODUCTION == 'false' and INJECT_FAKE_DATA == 'true':
    # Code here

Expected Behavior:
The environment should only initialize once per test run, and the condition in settings.py should not cause the environment to reload.
Actual Behavior:
The environment reloads twice, and the second initialization causes inconsistent behavior, leading to test failures.
Question:
What could cause Django's test environment to initialize twice, and how can I ensure the conditional block in settings.py doesn’t interfere with the test execution? How can I properly manage this configuration for tests?
